# Jackson JSON Modify Object Before Serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am looking to modify an object right before it gets serialized.  I want to write a custom serializer to parse the object, then pass it to the default object serializer.

This is what I have:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 *
 * @author Me
 */
public class PersonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Person>{

    @Override
    public void serialize(Person value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        //This returns a modified clone of Person value.
        Person safePerson = PrivacyService.getSafePerson(value);

        provider.defaultSerializeValue(safePerson, jgen);

    }

}
```

But that just goes in an infinate loop.  I have also tried:

```
provider.findTypedValueSerializer(Person.class, true, null).serialize(safePerson, jgen, provider);
```

That works, but it doesn't parse any of the fields in the object.

I also tried using a `@JsonFilter` but it was extremely heavy and sextupled my load times.

Help! Thanks!

Comment: Why would you do this, do you want to hide something in the Person object before you send it back to the client?

Comment: Yes, I have a service that cleans out the Person object and returns a cleaned clone of it.  The thing is, that depending on why you are logged in as determines how much data is removed.

Comment: There are also cases where I am serializing an array with two different people in the array, and I need to remove different things from each.

Comment: Jackson views and views are intended to solve this sort of problem. http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews

Comment: Great find! From what I can see though, that would mean I would have to annotate every field on this class (and there are 40+) and then have to manage each.  That would be a little messy for what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I initially rejoiced over finding the @Nitroware's answer, it unfortunately does not work in Jackson 2.7.2 - `BeanSerializerFactory.instance.createSerializer` introspects `JsonSerializer` annotation on `Person` class again, which leads to infinite recursion and `StackOverflowError`.

The point where default serializer would be created if `@JsonSerializer` were absent on POJO class is the `BeanSerializerFactory.constructBeanSerializer` method. So let's just use this method directly. Since the method is `protected`, we make it visible via factory subclass and feed it with information about serialized class. Also, we replace deprecated `SimpleType.construct` method by its recommended replacement. Whole solution is:

```
public class PersonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<PersonSerializer> {

    static class BeanSerializerFactoryWithVisibleConstructingMethod extends BeanSerializerFactory {

        BeanSerializerFactoryWithVisibleConstructingMethod() {
            super(BeanSerializerFactory.instance.getFactoryConfig());
        }

        @Override
        public JsonSerializer<Object> constructBeanSerializer(SerializerProvider prov, BeanDescription beanDesc) throws JsonMappingException {
            return super.constructBeanSerializer(prov, beanDesc);
        }

    }

    private final BeanSerializerFactoryWithVisibleConstructingMethod defaultBeanSerializerFactory = new BeanSerializerFactoryWithVisibleConstructingMethod();

    private final JavaType javaType = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(Person.class);

    @Override
    public void serialize(Person value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        Person safePerson = PrivacyService.getSafePerson(value);
        JavaType type = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(Person.class);
        BeanDescription beanDescription = provider.getConfig().introspect(type);
        JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer = defaultBeanSerializerFactory.constructBeanSerializer(provider, beanDescription);
        defaultSerializer.serialize(safePerson, jgen, provider);
    }

}
```

Unlike `BeanSerializerModifier`-based solution where you are forced to declare and register special behaviour outside your custom serializer, with this solution special logic is still encapsulated in custom `PersonSerializer`.

Eventually the logic might be pushed up to custom `DefaultJsonSerializerAware` ancestor.

**UPDATE 2017-09-28:**

I found bug in reasoning stated above. Using sole `BeanSerializerFactory.constructBeanSerializer` method is not enough. If original class contains null fields, they are not in output. (The reason is the `constructBeanSerializer` method is indirectly called from `createAndCacheUntypedSerializer` method which later calls `addAndResolveNonTypedSerializer` method where `NullSerializer`s are added into `BeanPropertyWriter`s).)

Solution to this problem which seems correct to me and is quite simple is *to reuse all serialization logic, not only constructBeanSerializer method*. This logic starts in provider's `serializeValue` method. The only inappropriate thing is custom `JsonSerialize` annotation. So we redefine `BeanSerializationFactory` to pretend the introspected class (and only it - otherwise JsonSerialize annotations on field types would not apply) has no `JsonSerialize` annotation.

```
@Override
public void serialize(Person value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    Person safePerson = PrivacyService.getSafePerson(value);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = (ObjectMapper)jgen.getCodec();
    Class<?> entityClass = value.getClass();
    JavaType javaType = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(entityClass);
    DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl defaultSerializerProvider = (DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl) objectMapper.getSerializerProviderInstance();
    BeanSerializerFactory factoryIgnoringCustomSerializerOnRootClass = new BeanSerializerFactory(BeanSerializerFactory.instance.getFactoryConfig()) {
        @Override
        protected JsonSerializer<Object> findSerializerFromAnnotation(SerializerProvider prov, Annotated a) throws JsonMappingException {
            JsonSerializer<Object> result = javaType.equals(a.getType()) ? null : super.findSerializerFromAnnotation(prov, a);
            return result;
        }
    };
    DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl updatedSerializerProvider = defaultSerializerProvider.createInstance(defaultSerializerProvider.getConfig(), factoryIgnoringCustomSerializerOnRootClass);
    updatedSerializerProvider.serializeValue(jgen, value);
}
```

Note if you don't suffer with problem with nulls, previous solution is enough for you.

Answer (score 12):

Holy crap, after several hours of digging through this library, trying to write my own factory, and a thousand other things, I FINALLY got this stupid thing to do what I wanted:

```
public class PersonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Person>{

    @Override
    public void serialize(Person value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        Person safePerson = PrivacyService.getSafePerson(value);

        //This is the crazy one-liner that will save someone a very long time
        BeanSerializerFactory.instance.createSerializer(provider, SimpleType.construct(Person.class)).serialize(safePerson, jgen, provider);

    }

}
```

Comment: You can also use BeanSerilizerModifier. I have posted an example in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25513488/3537858

Answer (score 11):

Since Jackson 2.2 one might use the converter in JsonSerialize annotation:

`@JsonSerialize(converter = OurConverter.class)`

and the converter

`public class OurConverter extends StdConverter<IN, OUT>`

IN and OUT are same class if modifying object